# JavaFX and Future (Concurrency) Can't create Stage within Future construct

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, future

I'm trying to create a second `Stage` in a `JavaFX Application`. This `Stage` needs to be created within a `Runnable`, which contains a `Future` construct.

Little SSCCE:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private ExecutorService executor;
    private Stage primaryStage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        executor.submit(exec);


    }

    Runnable exec = new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Future<Boolean> future = executor.submit(new Callable<Boolean>(){

                @Override
                public Boolean call() throws Exception {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    boolean ret = false;

                    System.out.println("is called");                    
                    Stage st = new Stage();
                    System.out.println("is not called");

                    return ret;
                }});
            boolean output;
            try {
                output = future.get();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                output = false;
            }
            if(output){

                System.out.println(true);
            }
        }};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

As you can see, within the `Future`, a new `Stage` is created. The `System.out.println()` before the `Stage` is created is executed. But the `System.out.println()` after the creation is not executed.

Why is the `Application` hanging after the creation of the `Stage`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [JavaDocs for `Stage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html),

> Stage objects must be constructed and modified on the JavaFX
>   Application Thread.

So your code will throw an `IllegalStateException`. You need to construct the `Stage` on the FX Application Thread.

Comment: :( that's bad. I want to have some async behaviour on my Application, where I need to show a Dialog. Is this possible?

Comment: Like almost all UI toolkits, JavaFX is single threaded. You have to create the stage and show it on that thread, and any access to the scene graph must be on that thread. You can perform other actions in user-defined threads. Have a look at the [`Task`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) class for examples of background thread interaction. Maybe explain more clearly what you are trying to do and why you need a background thread.